# How a single program is shared with multiple clients? (Means do multiple client threads share same objects?)

Tags: java, php, multithreading, jvm

"How a single program is accessed by multiple clients"?

"Is any copy of the program generated for each client to consume the program"?

The question is too simple but still a bit confusing.
Consider a piece of pseudo-code below-

```
Class Some {
// Some code
}
main(){
Some s= new Some();
}
```

So, now if a client tries to access this piece of code an object 's' will be created.

The question is whether this object will be created for every client(or client request) who accesses the code or this object will be created once in a lifetime(means on the deployment of code)?

I know servlets (or any other container based on language) are used to handle client requests but I am asking about the program which we write to be consumed by multiple clients.

Comment: There are many, many ways for one program to be accessed by multiple clients. Can you provide more context about that nature of your program/stack/architecture?

Comment: The question uses words "program", "accessed", "clients", "copy", "generated", "client request" and "consume" in a very confusing way and way outside their commonly accepted meanings. It seems that the author does not understand some basic concepts. Writing an answer is impossible without a lot of guessing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the concept, I think you will need to delve into the details of Java Memory Model. I think this [link is a great resource for beginners](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html).

```
Class Some {
  // Some code
}
main(){
  Some s= new Some();
}
```

> The question is whether this object will be created for every client(or client request) who accesses the code or this object will be created once in a lifetime(means on the deployment of code) ?

When you pass/access s, that's passing the value of s, which is a reference to a Some object. (s itself is passed by value) that wouldn't change which object s referred to. Java is strictly pass-by-value)

When you change the value within that object using s.someDataMember, then looking at the value of someDataMember again by another client will see the updated value.

Basically, Java doesn't copy objects unless you really ask it to. Now I am referring to this in the context of same JVM process.

Now consider that this object is an immutable object.

Comment: I think if you read the article attached above on Java Memory Model your questions will be answered.

Comment: I read your article which says The heap contains all objects created in your Java application, regardless of what thread created the object. All the objects and object's member variables are stored on the heap along with the object itself. Now it narrows down my question to whether the object "s" will be created for each thread? (I think it will be created for each thread).

Comment: All allocated objects can only reside in heap and not in stack. Thread only holds the reference to such objects as local variable in their stack.

Comment: Objects on the heap can be accessed by all threads that have a reference to the object. When a thread has access to an object, it can also get access to that object's member variables. If two threads call a method on the same object at the same time, they will both have access to the object's member variables, but each thread will have its own copy of the local variables.